# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str when using dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary as listed below:

```
test = {'time': 1634936741449, 'ticker':
[{
 'symbol': 'T',
 'value': '1',
 },{
 'symbol': 'DT',
 'value': '2',
 },{
 'symbol': 'SDT',
 'value': '3',
 },{
 'symbol': 'USDT',
 'value': '4',
 },{
 'symbol': 'N-USDT',
 'value': '5',
 },{
 'symbol': 'NKN-USDT',
 'value': '6',
 }]}
```

I am trying to print only specific variable which is `value`.

I tried the following `print` statement:

```
print(test["ticker"]["value"])
```

but i got this error

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I know i can do this by loops would be something like: `print(test["ticker"][i]['value'])` i tested this and it works, but i want a way without using loop.

The final output should be as following:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Comment: Cannot be done without (implicit) loop

Comment: this is what i thought but i shared this one hoping some could help.

Comment: you can do something on the lines of `map(itemgetter("value"), test["ticker])`

Comment: what does it mean by "itemgetter"

Comment: You could do `test["ticker"][0]["value"]`, `test["ticker"][1]["value"]`, etc... but why? You could get all of the values in a list `[ticker["value"] for ticker in test["ticker"]]`. That's a good way to do it, but its a loop. This is kinda a loopy thing.

Comment: is a function that you can import from operator "from operator import itemgetter"

Comment: @DaniMesejo - that's just hiding the loop in `map`.

Comment: @tdelaney I'm aware see my first comment.

Comment: @DaniMesejo - I'm aware that you are aware. I'm just making it explicit here in the comments that `map` loops. `map` is rarely useful - list comprehensions and generators are built into the language, no need for external functions like map.

Comment: Is there some reason to avoid looping?

Answer (score 0):

To have the final output as required, without using an explicit loop, you could try:

```
mylist = list(map(lambda d: d['value'], test['ticker']))

print(*mylist, sep='\n')
```

Edit:
**If you really want to avoid looping**, you could do this trick to move to a Pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(test['ticker'])
mylist = df['value'].tolist()
print(*mylist, sep='\n')
```